# Client side rendering and authentication

Tags: authentication, single-page-application, restful-authentication

I'm building a web app where all the rendering is to be done on the client side. The browser will make async requests back to the server for various resources and render the page.

The app currently protects some resources (POSTing to some endpoints to create records etc.) using oauth. If I write a server side rendering component, accessing these resources takes me to a login form on the oauth provider and the rest.

With a client side rendering system, I'm unsure how to go about it. I'm not sure what other details are needed so I can fill them in as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If user trying to access a restricted area, your server need to return something that your client will know and redirect user to login page.
For example, your server do the authentication and return a JSON object like this when user need to login:

```
{requireLogin: true, loginUrl: “https://login.com”}
```

And then, your client code receive that data and do the redirection:

```js
If(requireLogin===true)
   Window.location(loginUrl);
```

This project done exactly what you are asking: 
https://github.com/similik/similik

It follows client rendering approach with authentication implemented.